# Prevent row names to be written to file when using write.csv

Tags: r, csv

Commands:

```
t <- data.frame(v = 5:1, v2 = 9:5)
write.csv(t, "t.csv")
```

Resulting file:

```
# "","v","v2"
# "1",5,9
# "2",4,8
# "3",3,7
# "4",2,6
# "5",1,5
```

How do I prevent first column with row index from being written to the file?

Answer (score 363, accepted):

```
write.csv(t, "t.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

From `?write.csv`:

```
row.names: either a logical value indicating whether the row names of
          ‘x’ are to be written along with ‘x’, or a character vector
          of row names to be written.
```

Comment: I am ashamed because I did try ?write.csv but... Thx aix!

Comment: Yeah, the trick is to understand that this column represents row names.

Comment: Maybe one should rename this.

Comment: Would there be a way to make it that row.names = FALSE is the default? It is always frustrating in complex pipelines when a single script used the TRUE default and always causes a headache...

Answer (score 13):

For completeness, `write_csv()` from the [`readr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html) package is faster and never writes row names

```
# install.packages('readr', dependencies = TRUE)
library(readr)
write_csv(t, "t.csv")
```

If you need to write big data out, use `fwrite()` from the [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package. It's much faster than both `write.csv` and `write_csv`

```
# install.packages('data.table')
library(data.table)
fwrite(t, "t.csv")
```

Below is a [benchmark](https://edomt.github.io/File-IO-Storage/) that Edouard published on his site

```
microbenchmark(write.csv(data, "baseR_file.csv", row.names = F),
               write_csv(data, "readr_file.csv"),
               fwrite(data, "datatable_file.csv"),
               times = 10, unit = "s")

## Unit: seconds
##                                              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
##  write.csv(data, "baseR_file.csv", row.names = F) 13.8066424 13.8248250 13.9118324 13.8776993 13.9269675 14.3241311    10
##                 write_csv(data, "readr_file.csv")  3.6742610  3.7999409  3.8572456  3.8690681  3.8991995  4.0637453    10
##                fwrite(data, "datatable_file.csv")  0.3976728  0.4014872  0.4097876  0.4061506  0.4159007  0.4355469    10
```