# Remove index column in read.csv

Tags: r, csv

Inspired by [Prevent row names to be written to file when using write.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484325/remove-index-column-in-write-csv), I am curious if there a way to ignore the index column in R using the `read.csv()` formula.  I want to import a text file into an RMarkdown document and don't want the row numbers to show in my HTML file produced by RMarkdown.

Running the following code

```
write.csv(head(cars), "cars.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

produces a CSV that looks like this:

```
speed   dist
 4      2
 4      10
 7      4
 7      22
 8      16
 9      10
```

But, if you read this index-less file back into R (ie, `read.csv("cars.csv")`), the index column returns:

```
.   speed dist
1    4     2
2    4     10
3    7     4
4    7     22
5    8     16
6    9     10
```

I was hoping the solution would be as easy as including `row.names=FALSE` to the `read.csv()` statement, as is done with `write.csv()`, however after I run `read.csv("cars.csv", row.names=FALSE)`, R gets sassy and returns an "invalid 'row.names' specification" error message.

I tried `read.csv("cars.csv")[-1]`, but that just dropped the speed column, not the index column.

How do I prevent the row index from being imported?

Comment: Is the difference between `row.names=FALSE` and `row.names="FALSE"` a typo in your question or in your code?

Comment: fat fingers; I'll update my question

Comment: @HipHopPhysician, I doubt that there is a way that would allow you to remove the indices. This is something that R IDEs, including RStudio, will always have. But if you find a solution to remove the indices, please do share!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save your object, you won't have row names.

```
     x <- read.csv("cars.csv")
```

But if you print it (to HTML), you will use the print.data.frame function. Which will show row numbers by default. If I use the following (as last line) in my markdown chunk, I didn't have row numbers displayed:

```
 print(read.csv("cars.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Why?:** This problem seems associated with a previous subset procedure that created the data.  I have a file that keeps coming back with a pesky index column as I round-trip the data via read/write.csv.

**Bottom Line:** read.csv takes a file completely and outputs a dataframe, but the file has to be read before any other operation, like dropping a column, is possible.

**Easy Workaround:** Fortunately it's very simple to drop the column from the new dataframe:

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")
df <- df[,-1]
```