# `rbind` unique entries of all columns of a data frame and write it to a csv file

Tags: r, dataframe

```
##Initialise empty dataframe
g <-data.frame(x= character(), y= character(),z=numeric())

## Loop through each columns and list out unique values (with the column name)
for(i in 1:ncol(iris))
{
a<-data.frame(colnames(iris)[i],unique(iris[,i]),i)
g<-rbind(g,a)
setNames(g,c('x','y','z'))
}
## write the output to csv file
write.csv(g,"1.csv")
```

The output CSV file is something like this

[image]

Now the Column headers I want are not proper. I want column headers to be 'x','y','z' respectively. Also the first column should not be there.

Also if you have any other efficient way to do this, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You can change the column names like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081514/3519000, you can skip the row names like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484325/prevent-row-names-to-be-written-to-file-when-using-write-csv. and as for the efficiency of your loop, I would suggest you again to look around in StackOverflow first. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(iris))
{
a<-data.frame(colnames(iris)[i],unique(iris[,i]),i)
g<-rbind(g,a)
}
g <- setNames(g,c('x','y','z'))   ## note the `g <-`
write.csv(g, file="1.csv", row.names = FALSE)   ## don't write row names
```

`setNames` returns a new data frame with names "x", "y" and "z", rather than updating the input data frame `g`. You need the explicit assignment `<-` to do the "replacement". You may hide such `<-` by using either of the two

```
names(g) <- c('x','y','z')
colnames(g) <- c('x','y','z')
```

**Alternatively**, you can use the `col.names` argument inside `write.table`:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(iris))
{
a<-data.frame(colnames(iris)[i],unique(iris[,i]),i)
g<-rbind(g,a)
}
write.table(g, file="a.csv", col.names=c("x","y","z"), sep =",", row.names=FALSE)
```

`write.csv()` does not support `col.names`, hence we use `write.table(..., sep = ",")`. Trying to use `col.names` in `write.csv` will generate a warning.

---

**A more efficient way**

I would avoid using `rbind` inside a loop. I would do:

```
x <- lapply(iris, function (column) as.character(unique(column)))
g <- cbind.data.frame(stack(x), rep.int(1:ncol(iris), lengths(x)))
write.table(g, file="1.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=c("x","y","z"), sep=",")
```

Read `?lapply` and `?stack` for more.

Comment: I would like to have one more column in data frame (g)/csv file (say labels). It would repeat from 1 to n based on number of unique entries for a column. Example: For sepal.length it would start from 1 to 35...then for sepal.width it would again start from 1 upto 22.