# Process ID of nohup process continually updating - cant kill process

Tags: shell, command-line, nohup

I am trying to kill a nohup process in an EC2 instance but so far have been unsuccessful. I am trying to grab the process ID (PID) and then use it with the kill command in terminal, like so:

```
[ec2-user@ip-myip ~]$ ps -ef |grep nohup 
ec2-user 16580 16153  0 19:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nohup
```

with columns, (I believe) they're:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
ec2-user 16580 16153  0 19:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nohup
```

However, each time I try to kill the process, I get an error saying that the PID doesn't exist, seemingly because the PID changed. Here is a sequence I am running into in my command line:

```
// first try, grab the PID and kill
[ec2-user@ip-myip ~]$ ps -ef |grep nohup 
ec2-user 16580 16153  0 19:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nohup

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-213 ~]$ kill 16580
-bash: kill: (16580) - No such process


// ?? - check for correct PID again, and try to kill again
[ec2-user@ip-myip ~]$ ps -ef |grep nohup 
ec2-user 16583 16153  0 19:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nohup

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-213 ~]$ kill 16583
-bash: kill: (16583) - No such process

// try 3rd time, kill 1 PID up
[ec2-user@ip-myip ~]$ ps -ef |grep nohup 
ec2-user 16584 16153  0 19:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nohup

[ec2-user@ip-myip ~]$ kill 16585
-bash: kill: (16585) - No such process
```

This is quite a struggle for me right now, since I need to kill/restart this nohup process. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT - I tried this approach to killing the process because it was posted as an answer in this thread ([Prevent row names to be written to file when using write.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484325/prevent-row-names-to-be-written-to-file-when-using-write-csv)) and was the 2nd highest rated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very very bad question ...

1. You are trying to kill you `grep` process...

   ```
   ec2-user 16580 16153  0 19:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nohup
   ```

The command is `grep --color=auto nohup`

2. I'm not sure you can kill nohup

`nohup` will run your command in a particular way. But after its launching, the `nohup` process dies.

Comment: could you elaborate before I mess this up really bad on my end?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grep the ps output :

```
ps -ef | grep '[n]ohup'
```

or

```
pgrep -fl nohup
```

because you are trying to kill not nohup pid but the grep itself...